# Installing TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having issues installing tensorflow to my anaconda navigator. Below is the error message I got when installing through anaconda promot [Tensorflow Error Messge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcMFL.png)

Comment: It appears to be telling you that your python version is too new, perhaps you want to use a python version within the range stated in the error message.

Comment: If you want to use Python 3.8, you can try other installation methods outside of conda: https://www.tensorflow.org/install

Comment: Thanks for the response. The linked shared is for win64. I presently used win32. Is there a link for win32

Comment: @Lash360, Tensorflow 2 supports win64 bit system only. You can check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install tensorflow is by creating environment of python 3.5

1. Open your anaconda prompt powershell
2. enter "conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda" //py35 is your env name (change as u please)
3. enter "conda activate py35" //entering the env
4. install required packages using conda or pip
   eg: "conda install tensorflow" or "pip install tensorflow"
5. install spyder "conda install spyder"
6. enter spyder
7. to deactivate "conda deactivate py35"

you can activate env whenever using "conda activate py35"

this helped me. Hope it will work for you.